# How Do I Remove Ubuntu?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I got Ubuntu just to try it out.  It said at installation that I would be able to choose which OS I wanted to run (Windows 7 or Ubuntu) at start up.  However, it doesn't let me choose OS at start up.

It wouldn't be such a big deal (because Ubuntu is pretty neat) but Ubuntu doesn't load right.  I'm constantly restarting my computer 6 or so times because it's continually freezing after the Login screen.  What can I do to remove Ubuntu and go back to Windows 7.

I have to remove Ubuntu through Ubuntu.  It will not load Windows 7 for me at all.  I'm very new to Ubuntu, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This was [asked and answered here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on), so that should help you. As for the specific problems you're having with Ubuntu, if you think you might want to keep Ubuntu if you can solve those problems, you might consider posting one or (if they're separate issues) more new questions asking specifically about them.

Comment: This was EXTREMELY helpful, and I'm going to try it.  Thank you SO VERY much!